# Differential Equation Direction field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, vector-fields

### What i want to achieve:

I want to plot the **direction fields** of the following three **differential equations**:

**1. Malthusian growth model:** $p'(t)=\lambda*p(t)$ with $\lambda=1$ and $p(t)=t$

**2. Linear growth model with saturation:** $p'(t)=\lambda_0-\lambda_1*p(t)$ with $\lambda_0=1, \lambda_1=2$ and $p(t)=t$

**3. Logistic growth model:** $p'(t)=a*p(t)-b*p(t)^2$

---

### What i have done so far:

For **1.** and **2.** i have used **Matlab** to produce the direction fields. The code reads as follows:

```
%Malthusian growth model
[x,t]=meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);
dt = 1*t;
dx=ones(size(dt));
quiver(x,t,dx,dt);
```

[image: Malthusian growth Model]

```
%Linear growth model with saturation
[x,t]=meshgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:1);
dt = 1-2*t;
dx=ones(size(dt));
quiver(x,t,dx,dt);
```

[image: Linear growth model with saturation]

Please note that on the picture for 2. at $\frac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_1}=\bar{p}=\frac{1} {2}=0.5$ the slopes have 0 inclination. (**point of equilibrium**)

---

### What doesn't work:

**Firstly**, I am not 100% sure wether the direction fields for **1.** and **2.** are correct. I need an OK or NOT OK or NOT 100% OK on both.

**Secondly**: The logistic growth model has a **point of equilibrium** at $\bar{p}=\frac{a}{b}$. 
But my problem is that my direction field in Matlab does not "hit" the **point of equilibrium** (like it is for example the case in the **Linear growth model with saturation plot** depicted in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjKrI.png)). I produce a plot for 3. using the following code:

```
%Logistic growth model
[x,t]=meshgrid(0:1:12,0:1:12);
dt = 1*t-0.1*t^2;
dx=ones(size(dt));
quiver(x,t,dx,dt);
```

[image: Logistic growth model]

According to $\bar{p}=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{1}{0.1}=10$ there should be the **point of equilibrium** at 10. But obviously the slopes are not 0. What can i do to produce a plot similar (without the black solution lines) to the following one, in which there is clear convergence to the point of equilibrium visible from all starting values:

[image: logistic growth correct]

---

### EDIT:

After changing the code for equation/plot **3.** to:

```
%Logistic growth model
[x,t]=meshgrid(0:1:12,0:1:12);
dt = 1*t-0.1*t.^2;
dx=ones(size(dt));
quiver(x,t,dx,dt);
```

The plot had the desired characteristics in terms of the point of equilibirum:

[image: Logarithmic Growth model corrected]

Comment: Just for the sake of being sure: could you please try to write dt = 1*t-0.1*t.^2; instead of your line? Notice the dot after t.

Comment: @Evgeny: I dont know what the "." after "t" does, but i think my plot has the desired form now and the point of equilibrium is observable.

Comment: Well, in Matlab if t is a square matrix then t^2 means usual matrix multiplication. But that's not what you want in this case: you want to take element-wise square of each element of your matrix. So that's what this dot for: you are telling MATLAB that you want an element-wise operation. It's not so hard to forget about this subtlety though :)

Comment: As for first two plots -- they look the same way as they should. Is everything OK with 3rd plot now? Anyway, please update it.

Comment: @Evgeny: Yes everything is OK with the 3. plot, after editing it as you proposed.

Comment: @Amzoti: From the code line $dt = 1*t-0.1*t^2$ and $\bar{p}=\frac{a}{b}$, it must follow that $a=1$, $b=0.1$ and $p(t)=t$.

Comment: @Amzoti: Yes you can do that. Maybe some other User needs it.

Comment: @Evgeny: You can post your comments as an answer to the question.